# Using Test Mail Server Tool with WAMP?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to send some test mail to myself while working on a PHP script. I've researched some other questions and it led me to this tool:

http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Others have said that it works perfectly but I'm having trouble using it myself. My php.ini files should be reset to default values as I tried to change the SMTP values at one point, but now they are back to "smtp.wlink.com.np".

For anyone that has used this tool, how does it work? Where do I have to send the e-mail to?

```
$to = "localhost";
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set the php.ini SMTP settings to `127.0.0.1` and port `25`.
2. Send the email to anyone, any address (i.e., send it to obama@whitehouse.gov).

The tool will "intercept" the email, and show it to you. The email will never leave your system.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Do I need to change where the e-mail was sent from in php.ini? Right now it is you@yourdomain.com

Also is it the php.ini file in \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin or the one in \wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12? My search results return two php.ini's.

Comment: @skeletonne, I don't know the php.ini path of WampServer (I use WampDeveloper). But do check the Windows Firewall to see if it's blocking "TestmailServerToolSetup.exe". Also check the website's, Apache's, and PHP's error log files to make sure it's not a problem with your test code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I think it was the way I was writing the mail() function test. I had already given permission for the program to go through the firewall.